# Что должно учитываться при идеальной блокировке (бане)?

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Есть php сайт мини версия социальной системы нужно создать возможность блокировки другого пользователя,

Какие параметры нужно учесть для идеальной блокировки 
чтобы он не смог,  использовав новый аккаунт обойти блок?

Например facebook  после блокировки 
моего аккаунта пользователем я не могу достучатся(найти его) даже сменив  аккаунт, мне тоже нужна такая блокировка.

Можно ли считать facebook блокировку идеальным
и как можно например его обойти ?

Comment: привязывайте аккаунт к номеру тлф и будет вам счастие

Comment: А как фейсбук защищается от обхода вида «Вась, дай свой телефон на пару минут, я с твоего аккаунта на фейсбуке немножко посижу»?

Comment: @teran сервисы приема смс не согласны. Любая блокировка обходиться на раз, если есть сильное желание

Answer (score 1):

Нужно чтобы один пользователь запрещал другому пользователю посещать свою страницу?

Это просто. Для каждого пользователя храним черный список заблокированных пользователей.

Если пользователь из черного списка обращается к странице - показываем ему заглушку. 
Надо еще решить что делать с пользователями без авторизации - скорее всего их тоже не пускать.

Comment: На уровне базы данных это легко можно сделать,  мне интересует 
какие есть другие параметры  там  IP  адрес или другое.
Что учитывает  facebook   или другие  социальные сети?

Comment: Учитывай все что можешь и что не лень: 1) айпи (за ним могут быть тысячи пользователей), 2) записанные куки, 3) записанные данные localStorage, File и IndexedDB API, а также Isolated Storage, Application Cache, SDCH  4) User Agent 5) размеры экрана 6)  Last-Modified, ETag 7) вплоть до поведенческого анализа - как двигает мышью, % увеличения экрана, предпочитаемый язык, дефолтная кодировка, часовой пояс

Comment: А  как это поможет при блокировке, ну кроме ip ?

Comment: ровно так же как и айпи.